# clear interval and animate doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Everything works except the marked line. If the line is replaced by the commented one - it works. Any help?

```js
var goev = setInterval(fgoev, 2000);

function fgoev() {
  $('#eventwrap').animate({
    bottom: 0
  }, 900).delay(5000).animate({
    bottom: -10
  }, 100).animate({
    bottom: 0
  }, 100).animate({
    bottom: -10
  }, 100).animate({
    bottom: 0
  }, 100);
}

$('#evclose').click(function() {
  clearInterval(goev);
  $('#eventwrap').animate({
    bottom: -125
  }, 900); // doesn't work
  //$('#eventwrap').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='eventwrap'>
  <div id='evclose'>X</div>
  <a href='event.php' target='_blank' id='evinside'>
    <div id='evmore'>MORE</div>
    <div id='evtitleleft'>Days</div>
    <div id='evtitleright'>Hours</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div id='evdays'>
      <?php echo $diffa; ?>
    </div>
    <div id='evhours'>
      <?php echo $diffb ?>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? No animation at all or is it at the wrong position etc. And why is clear interval not working? I noticed your function and interval id variable have the same name, maybe not a good idea to do that.

Comment: @xander, `doesn't work` means `nothing happens`

Comment: @xander, I change the function name - without success

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS to the question. It's almost impossible to fix something we can't see - especially when that may be causing the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I added html code and suppose this is not important because the last line of `js` code works, but anyway - html is there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, my `eventwrap` is fixed position, so it can move. Also, on your fiddle click on `X`  - does nothing, at least the first circle of TimeInterval is over.

Comment: Yes I was confused as you missed the CSS from the question. I added a working solution for you in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you need to clear all the animations which have been queued up on the `#eventwrap` element before you set the new bottom position in the `#evclose` event handler. To do that you can use `stop(true)`, like this:

```js
var goev = setInterval(fgoev, 2000);

function fgoev() {
  $('#eventwrap').animate({ bottom: 0 }, 900).delay(5000)
    .animate({ bottom: -10 }, 100)
    .animate({ bottom: 0 }, 100)
    .animate({ bottom: -10 }, 100)
    .animate({ bottom: 0 }, 100);
}

$('#evclose').click(function() {
  clearInterval(goev);
  $('#eventwrap').stop(true, true).animate({
    bottom: -125
  }, 900);
});
```

```css
#eventwrap { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='eventwrap'>
  <div id='evclose'>X</div>
  <a href='event.php' target='_blank' id='evinside'>
    <div id='evmore'>MORE</div>
    <div id='evtitleleft'>Days</div>
    <div id='evtitleright'>Hours</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div id='evdays'>
      <?php echo $diffa; ?>
    </div>
    <div id='evhours'>
      <?php echo $diffb ?>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I would also suggest that you look in to using a CSS keyframe animation to move the `#eventwrapper` instead of the clunky and slow JS animation methods which jQuery offers.

Comment: seems it works now. thanks a lot. Could you give me any example, or related link to css keyframe animation, pls ?

Comment: but is it possible to run, stop...etc this kind of animation using jquery? As you can see I need to stop this animation by clicking on a div?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You attach the keyframe animation to a class and then use JS to add/remove the class. You'll find that CSS animations are much smoother as they are hardware accelerated. JS is not.